# Sourcebook for Forgotten Realms in D&D 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, forgotten-realms, lore

After years of RPG abstinence, I am currently exploring the 5th edition of D&D with the Starter Set.

While previous editions had dedicated sourcebooks that would describe the geography, culture, history and background of [Forgotten Realms](http://dnd.wizards.com/dungeons-and-dragons/what-is-dd/forgotten-realms), which seem to be the "default setting" for many adventures, I am missing such a book for 5e.

The only book I could find seems to be the rather thin and geographically focused ["Sword Coast Adventurer’s Guide"](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/sc-adventurers-guide).

Is there a reference available for the 5th edition that would provide the described background information in detail instead of discussing rules and game mechanics?

As a new player such a guide would really help to develop a better understanding of the environment and design and handle your character more effectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### There is no such book... yet.

As of July 31, 2018 there is no 5th edition Forgotten Realms campaign guide besides the first section of Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide (SCAG).

It is likely we will get such a book eventually (we've gotten a playtest book similar to SCAG for Eberron recently), but for now the adventure modules take place either in regions near the Sword Coast or on planes beyond the Prime Material so it hasn't been necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So would you say that "Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide" (SCAG) is a recommended buy for someone new to D&D?

Comment: @TitusQuinn if you plan on running a campaign in the Forgotten Realms it is very helpful for sure. Not strictly necessary, but it will help you understand better the current state of the world for a more immersive experience.